# SQL query to group by and order by timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hey guys, I've tried to get this right but I can't, maybe you can point me in the right direction

I have 3 columns, 'url_id', 'timestamp' and 'o'.  I need to group by 'url_id' and sort by the most current timestamp.

table "example"

```
timestamp | url_id   |    o
----------------------------
2000      | 1        |   50
2007      | 1        |   70
2011      | 1        |   90
2001      | 2        |   20
2006      | 2        |   50
2009      | 2        |   40
2011      | 2        |   10
```

'o' is the value at the end I want.  I was trying to do this with a subquery but kept getting the oldest value (tried order by, and had no luck).

What am I doing wrong?  Is what I'm looking for actually require a subquery?

Comment: So what would you expect? If you group by url_id and sort by timestamp the result is correct (ordering is applied to the groups)

Comment: Do you want for `url_id=1` to show `2011 | 1 | 90` ? If yes, then a subquesry or a `JOIN` will be needed.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT url_id
     , MAX(timestamp) AS currentTS
  FROM yourTable
  GROUP BY url_id
  ORDER BY currentTS DESC
```

Aftre you last explanation, I think you need to JOIN the above query to your original table, like this:

```
SELECT y.timestamp
     , y.url_id
     , y.o
FROM yourTable y
JOIN 
    ( SELECT url_id
           , MAX(timestamp) AS currentTS
      FROM yourTable
      GROUP BY url_id
    ) AS grp
  ON grp.url_id = y.url_id
    AND grp.currentTS = y.timestamp
ORDER BY y.timestamp DESC
```

**Note:** if there are two (or more) rows with same url_id and same timestamp, they'll both (or all) appear at the results.

Comment: Actually I am wrong, not exactly how I wanted it, your comment above is probably what I am looking for.

Comment: What I want to output is  2011 | 1| 90   and 2011 | 2 | 10